# Making an object of template class

Tags: c++, qt, templates, object

I have a template class defined :

```
 template <class T>
    class TempClass
    {
    ...
    };
```

If I want to make an object of this class in let's say some MyClass.h to access functions of template class, how shall I pass the argument of the template?
I tried to do the following:

```
class MyClass{
public:
    TempClass<T> temp;
}
```

Sure, as supposed it does not work, as T is not defined in MyClass, so I am a bit lost how do it correctly.

Thanks.

Comment: I didn't understand it well. What are you trying to achieve? Create a class (`MyClass`) in generic way or just instantiante a specific kind of template object? For the second case, to instantiate it for int, just define object as `TempClass<int> temp;`

Comment: `T` is not a type by itself, it's a formal "type parameter". If you say e.g. `TempClass<int> temp;` the compiler will generate the code for a new class `TempClass<int>` that corresponds to the template `TempClass` with all instances of "`T`" replaced with "`int`", and `temp` will be an object of that new type. Now it should be clear that you can't "pass `T`", so can you clarify what you want to do?

Comment: @Tomás Badan Actually what I want to achieve is calling functions which are defined in TempClass from MyClass.

Comment: @gx_ Thanks for the answer. So if I need to call function for let's say 3 different types, I need to have 3 objects of template class to achieve it?

Comment: @Mike You example does not give enough information for me the answer precisely... (If your "3 types" are fixed and known when you write the code for `MyClass` then maybe yes (but not necessarily _member_ variables, and if the functions to call are `static` you don't need objects), else you may want to make `MyClass` itself a template as shown in answers below...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `MyClass` to be a template as well, you would do it like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct MyClass {
    TempClass<T> temp;
};
```

(You could also use `class` instead of `struct`, but since all members are public, you don't really need default private.)

If you don't want `MyClass` to be a template, you will need some concrete type to substitute in for `T`.  For example:

```
struct MyClass {
    TempClass<string> temp;
};
```

**Pedantic:**  Technically `TempClass` isn't a *template class*, it's a *class template*.  A class template isn't actually a class, it's a template that can be used to create individual classes that are themselves template classes.  Thus, `TempClass` is a class template, while `TempClass<string>` is a template class --- a class that is created by instantiating a template.

Answer (score 2):

Templates are not classes. Are. as it name means, templates wich helps the compiler to create classes. That is, if you have a template class `template<typename T> class Foo{};`:

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
    T attribute;
};
```

Its only a template which the compiler uses to generate different versions of `Foo`, each for a specified type. When you **instantiate** a template, that is, tells the compiler you need that class generated with a specified type, the compiler generates a version of `Foo` code replacing the template argument with the specified type:

```
int main()
{
    Foo<int> foo_int_variable;
    Foo<bool> foo_bool_variable;
}
```

The compiler after seeing that two instances, generates code like this:

```
struct __Foo_int
{
    int attribute;
};

struct __Foo_bool
{
    bool attribute;
};
```

So the code of main is translated to this:

```
int main()
{
    __Foo_int foo_int_variable;
    __Foo_bool foo_bool_variable;
}
```

So the answer is: **You need to specify what type you need, to let the compiler to generate the correct template instantiation**.
If the class that uses `Foo`, like in your example, don't need a specific instantiation of Foo, needs a generic version of `Foo`, you could make that class a template too.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. It is a valuable answer.

Comment: @Mike my goal is to provide a complete description of ***"why you have to do this"***, not a ***"you have to do this"*** answer. I think that *yo have to do this* answers have to be downvoted, even if the answer is correct. When you post questions in sites like stackoverflow, you want a detailed description of your problem, followed by a list of possible solutions.

Comment: OK, I will consider that fact in future. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can instantiate your template like this, for example, to instantiate for int:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
  TempClass<int> temp;
};
```

But if you still want you MYClass to be generic, you can make it template too and define it like this:

```
template<typename T>
class MyClass
{
public:
  TempClass<T> temp;
};
```

and let the any MyClass object instantiation to define parameter T, for example:

```
MyClass<int> class;
```